# How can the score of a question be set to 0 if none of the options is requested on form submission in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

A quiz system is created in laravel. The database contains users, questions and results tables. The 'questions' table contains the question name, its 4 options and the correct option. The 'results' table contain user_id and question_id as foreign keys from other two tables and one column 'obtained_marks' which shows the mark obtained by user in each question.
If none of the options for any question is requested, the obtained_mark for the question(s) should be set to 0.
I used !isset($options[$i]) in the condition for obtained_marks for storing data in the 'results' table but it did not work.

Result Controller File:

public function store(Request $request){

```
    DB::beginTransaction();

    $questions=Question::all();
    
    if(empty($request->option)){

            foreach($questions as $question){

                $result = DB::table('results')->insert([
                'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                'question_id' => $question->id,
                'obtained_marks' => 0
            ]);
            
                
            }

            if ($result){
            DB::commit();
            return redirect()->route('login');
        }
        }
            $options= array_values($request->option);

            
                for($i=0; $i<count($questions); $i++){
                    
                    $result = DB::table('results')->insert([
                    'user_id' => auth()->user()->id,
                    'question_id' => $questions[$i]->id,
                    'obtained_marks' => (!isset($options[$i]) || $options[$i] != $questions[$i]->right_answer) ? 0:1
            ]);
        
            }

            if ($result){
                DB::commit();
                return redirect()->route('login');
            }

        
    }
```

View file:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-8 mx-auto">
            <br>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h1>Welcome to Quiz</h1>
                </div>
                <form class="form" action="{{ route('store') }}" method="POST">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card-body">
                        @foreach ($questions as $question)
                            <p>{{ $loop->iteration }}. {{ $question->question }}</p>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="radio" name="option[{{ $question->id }}]" id="option1"
                                        value="a" />
                                    <label for="option1"><button class="options" disabled>a.
                                            {{ $question->a }}</button></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="radio" name="option[{{ $question->id }}]" id="option2"
                                        value="b" />
                                    <label for="option2"><button class="options" disabled>b.
                                            {{ $question->b }}</button></label>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <br>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="radio" name="option[{{ $question->id }}]" id="option3"
                                        value="c" />
                                    <label for="option3"><button class="options" disabled>c.
                                            {{ $question->c }}</button></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <input type="radio" name="option[{{ $question->id }}]" id="option4"
                                        value="d" />
                                    <label for="option4"><button class="options" disabled>d.
                                            {{ $question->d }}</button></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary flex-item">Submit</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary flex-item">Reset</button>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@endsection

Error:

Undefined offset for options[$i]

Comment: Welcome to SO ... why are you calling `array_values` on the "options" input array?

Comment: because it was not accessing the value stored in array

Comment: If application's logic allows submit with no specific answer, first thing should be to set default value of `0` in migration. Second, in validation class, rule should be [`'sometimes'`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#validating-when-present) telling validator that sometimes there wouldn't be any value. In that case, saving it to DB, if not value there, DB would use default value already set in migration, which is `0`.

Comment: Tried it , but it's showing all results as 0 even if one or more are requested correctly.

Comment: Which line does the error `Undefined offset for options[$i]` occur?

Comment: obtained_marks' => (!isset($options[$i]) || $options[$i] != $questions[$i]->right_answer) ? 0:1. If we remove  !isset condition in this line. Then it shows undefined offset

Comment: If !isset is used then it returns all results as 0

Answer (score 0):

`Undefined offset for options[$i]` means you may be trying to use the key of an array that is not set. so I suppose you are searching for the option which is not sent by the form request. (the client has not checked any option for some of the questions)

although I tested your scenario with `!isset()` and it worked, I suggest using `array_key_exists()` instead since `!isset()` does not return `false` for array keys that correspond to a null value.

Comment: Still showing 0 for all questions.

Comment: you should check the `$questions` and `$options` then, to ensure that the `$question[$i]->right_answer` and `$option[$i]` are the same in **value and the data type**, in case the user has sent the correct option.